# Return one dimensional array instead of multi

Tags: php, arrays

Ok so I'm wanting just the years returned as a one dimensional array instead of a multi when pulling from the database:

```
public function getYears($make = null, $model = null) {

    // select table
    $this->select(array('DISTINCT year'));
    $this->table($this->table);

    // build where clause
    if( $make !== null && $model !== null ) {
        $this->where('make', '=', $make);
        $this->and_where('model', '=', $model);
    } elseif( $make !== null && $model === null ) {
        $this->where('make', '=', $make);
    } elseif( $make === null && $model !== null ) {
        $this->where('model', '=', $model);
    }

    return $this->all();

}
```

This function basically just returns `SELECT DISTINCT year FROM vehicle;`
In another script, I'm doing:

```
$years = $vehicle->getYears();
```

However it returns as so:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'year' => string '2014' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
```

I want it to just return as so:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '2014' (length=4)
  1 => string '2013' (length=4)
```

Is that possible? Because I'm putting it through my select form helper function that takes a one dimensional array of all your options and loops through them. But it can't loop through a multi-list because it's trying to echo out the index which is unfortunately an array.. not a string.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: yes, very possible. What have you tried

Comment: That's all I've tried. I can't figure anything out. I don't want to touch my select function because it is used throughout many other scripts to help build my forms.

Comment: You need to do this in the `all()` method or create another method to use that returns it how you want.

Comment: So I have to loop through the results twice? That's kind of icky...

Comment: maybe it's possible to foreach thgough your result and assign manually to your array line by line, with something like fetch() instead of all() ?

Comment: You can modify `all($column=null)` so that if a column is passed it returns the way you want or if column is omitted it returns the way it does now.

Comment: My all() method is like this : 
`$this->execute();
return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Abra, is that the only way of doing it?

Comment: AbraCadaver idea it's most likely to be the best choice if you have plan to reuse the concept of returing single value instead of all the data in other places. Else just perform a foreach on your $years ,and get the data in the format you want before using it.

Comment: Several ways to do it.  I posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example, needs error checking / check for valid column, etc...

```
public function all($column=null) {
    $this->execute();

    if($column === null) {
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    while($row = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row[$column];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Or create another method `all_single($column)` or something and use that instead.  No need to loop through the results of `all()`.  The only time you'll need this is if you only get a single column.

Also you can restructure this based on whether you like to `return once` or `return early` as shown.

Answer (score 0):

You either edit your All method, create a new method such as AllOneDimentional (not a great name!) or you take the data returned from All and manipulate it:

```
foreach($years as $year)
    $onedimyears[]=$year['year'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past when i've attempted this i've used this function

```
function flatten(array $array) {
$return = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
return $return;
```

}

It's as about as efficient as you can get assuming your on php 5.3 or greater